# Sitecore Comment Module

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I am trying to develop with Sitecore 6.5.

The requirement includes the `comment feature` for both articles and images.

They want a simple `WYSIWYG` editor and able to upload images.

I believe Sitecore does not have built in feature for this.

I am lookin at sdn and marketplace using keyword `comment feature` but unable to find any related feature.

Is there any related feature for this even if it does not fulfill all requirements.

Answer (score 2):

There's also the [Facebook Comments Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/), possibly useful if you are using the [Social Connected](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Social%20Connected%20Module.aspx) module, but it really depends on how much control you need/want.

We've previously rolled our own commenting system, it was just text no image upload. Thing to be careful about is the comments need to be added to the master database as well, otherwise you will lose them next time you do a full publish. Depending on your server architecture this may give you some problems, since our CD instances did not have access to the master DB we had write some web services deployed to our CMS environment (even then it was a hassle getting the ports opened). This did have the advantage that we were able to put all the comments through Workflow and Approval process before being published to our site though.

Comment: ye, i have proposed social commenting such as facebook. but they insist they want it to b their own commenting system.

Comment: I can understand that, people want control over their own commenting system. Do the comments need to go into Sitecore and through the approval process? How many number of comments do you think you will have? Sitecore may not be the right tool if it is a high number.

Comment: Jackpot. that is the reason Sitecore doesn't have any modules for commenting system, isn't it?

Comment: It's really going to depend on numbers - Sitecore's main issue is when you have over 100 child items, but you can get around that limitation by dividing this up into smaller chunks, e.g. most news based implementation will split the "news" section my year/month/day folders. Also now there is [Item Buckets](http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_Item_Buckets.aspx) which will handle big data.

Comment: It's partly going to depend on your req's, do you need control, approval process, do you want to build a login/verification system etc.

Comment: we need login system to comment (text and image). but there is no approve system. however, admin can delete comments which are not appropriate.

Comment: Well you can roll your own, but you would need to handle everything yourself - login, validation, flag as inappropriate, deletions etc etc.  You might want to ask Sitecore directly for what they used on their marketplace site.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the [Forum Modul](http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_YAF.aspx)e and [Weblog Module](http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/WeBlog.aspx) on Sitecore Marketplace. They are not exactly what you need but do include functions to add comments and probably also uploads. As it is shared source, you can download the complete source and re-use the parts that you need.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to look into [DISQUS](http://disqus.com/).  It's not a Sitecore module, per say, but I've used it on Sitecore projects to meet commenting requirements in the past.  It's very easy to integrate into a site.